Regex with optional final capture group
How do I construct a regex pattern that matches the following examples with three capture groups like so:



example
grp1
grp2
grp3




foo:bar-alpha
foo
bar
alpha


foo:bar-beta
foo
bar
beta


foo:bar
foo
bar




grp3 is optional
Attempts:
(.*):(.*)(-(alpha|beta))  Matches only the first two cases but I want the last group to be optional..
(.*):(.*)(-(alpha|beta))? adding the ? quantifier matches all 3 but allows the second group to capture everything
I'm using Python regex
N.b. My actual input is confidential. The examples are representative.

Please show your actual input, without which we can't help you, then vote to reopen.

Perhaps you want ([^:]*:):([^-]*)(-(alpha|beta))*. where you say "everything that is not a colon, followed by colon, followed by everything that is not a hyphen.

([^:]*):([^-]*)(-(alpha|beta))? this one should work, notice that alpha or beta are stored in group 4 (if exist), you can test it here: regex101

@Tim, that would appear to match "::-alpha-alpha-alpha".

@Bohemian My actual input is confidential. The examples are representative.

The following regex gives the right groups for you examples:
^([^:]+):([^-]+)(?:-(.+))?$

It uses a non-capturing group ((?:...)) to make the third group optional without introducting a fourth group.
Split up and commented, as is supported when using re.VERBOSE, with all parts explained:
r = re.compile("""
    ^        # assert beginning of string.
    ([^:]+)  # first group: everything up to next colon.
    :        # literal colon as separator.
    ([^-]+)  # second group: everything until a hyphen appears:
             # now if there's no third part, that's it.
             # if there is no hyphen, group 2 will go to the end
             # of the line.
    (?:      # non-capturing group to make this part optional.
        -    # a literal hyphen.
        (.+) # anything until the end.
    )?       # make this group optional.
    $.       # assert end of string.
""", re.VERBOSE)

I have made the assumption that all three of your groups (if they are present) will need to have at least a length of one, meaning that foo:bar-, :bar and asdf:-qwer are all invalid inputs.
If any of this doesn't match your requirements, please elaborate and maybe add additional examples or explanation to your question.
